# sublime press key "escape" can't type anything

Tags: input, sublimetext3

[image]

My sublime version is 3083. When I press key "ESCAPE",the cursor changed, and I can't type code any-more. If I close it, and reopen the file. I can type again.

Through key-map, I change key bindings and delete the following code. It won't happen again. but I can't close some window in sublime like the window I open with Ctrl+F.

Does this happen to anyone else?

```
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "clear_fields", "context":
    [
        { "key": "has_next_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
},
{ "keys": ["escape"], "command": "clear_fields", "context":
    [
        { "key": "has_prev_field", "operator": "equal", "operand": true }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you in Vintage mode?

Comment: No, the sublime alrady ignored package Vintage

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I've had the exact same problem for a while and it annoyed me to no end. I've managed to figure out the issue and a solution so I'll post it here in case anyone else has this problem.

The problem is that the package "Vintage" is not in your ignored_packages setting.

To solve: 
Preferences->Settings

This should open both the global and user settings. 
In the user settings you will probably have something along the lines of :

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [

    ]
}
```

Simply change this to: (or add this to your user settings file)

```
{
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I upvoted but, I would like to know why Vintage is causing that issue. can the OP accept this answer

Comment: Accepted answer should be swapped to @Codoscope's answer below. This is a workaround, his shows the issue, and how to change back to insert mode

Comment: this works but could you explain what ignored_packages means? why Vintage not in there would cause the issue with the Esc key?

Answer (score 10):

When you hit the `escape` key, you enter under the *command mode*. You can see that you are in this mode at the bottom of Sublime Text's frame. In this mode, you can perform different actions with the keyboard, like using `h`, `j`, `k` and `l` keys to move the cursor and `d` `d` to remove a line. Those are similar to what you get with Vim's command mode.

**If you want to leave the command mode and go back to the *insert mode*, just hit `i`.**

Then, you will be able to write again, and you will see "INSERT MODE" back at the bottom of the frame:

[image: INSERT MODE]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by removing the **Vintagous** package I had installed many months ago.
I have no idea why this issue started to occur just a couple of days ago.

If you don't have **Vintagous** package installed
I suggest you check if any of your packages are using the "escape" keybinding (you can quickly find that out by using the **FindKeyConflicts** package) and check if the issue gets fixed by removing that package.

Hope this fix works for you.